# conda list doesn't show installed package

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I have been listing the packages in an environment using 'conda list'.  The list that is then produced doesn't include packages that I know are installed in the environment, in this case, flickrapi.

`((getpics)) C:\Users\Rdebbout>conda list fl
packages in environment at C:\Users\Rdebbout\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\getpics:
pyflakes                  1.1.0                    py27_0`

This is pointing to the correct environment and if you look below, when I am in the same environment, I can import flickrapi without a problem

```
    ((getpics)) C:\Users\Rdebbout>ipython
Python 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSCv.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    IPython 4.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from flickrapi import FlickrAPI

In [2]:
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: What does `where ipython` print out? Is it in the `getpics` environment?  You might want to try restarting your command prompt too.

Comment: where ipython -- prints out both .../Anaconda2/envs/getpics/Scripts/ipython.exe AND .../Anaconda2/Scripts/ipython.exe

Comment: ...seems like the packages are being read from the right environment, I still don't get why some don't show up in the list

Comment: How did you install `flickrapi`?

Comment: I used pip install